# How to change the home category url to friendly url in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

I  have changed the home category "link_rewrite" and saved in phpmyadmin.
When I refresh Home page and hover the view all menu it displays "en/category.php?id_category=1" How to change the url to friendly url in prestashop

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled friendly URLs ? Because it seems you did not enabled them.  If not then do it as followed:

1) Go to preferences and then click on SEO & URLs
2) Enable your SEO urls there, and refresh your page.

Check it and it will work.

If still issue remains, or you got any other issue, let me know. 
Thank you

Comment: i have enabled everything but still issue remains.

Comment: ok, can you show me the code how you placed the link? Or did you used a module? because if you enabled everything, then it should work fine. There may be something wrong in the code where the link is placed.